# rearange numpy multilevel array by column values

Tags: numpy

i wish to rearange numpy array by value of one of its columns. Meaning -

```
[[0, 0], [583, 0], [1166, 0], [1365, 0], [0, 583], [583, 583], [1166, 583], [1365, 583]]
```

to

```
[[[0, 0], [583, 0], [1166, 0], [1365, 0]], 
[[0, 583], [583, 583], [1166, 583], [1365, 583]]]
```

I currently reshape it with "hard coded" shape, but I wish to do it automaticaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code which covers the case of variable number of second row values:

```
X = np.array([[0, 0], [583, 0], [1166, 0], [1365, 0], [0, 583], [583, 583], [1166, 583], [1365, 583],
              [0, 1], [581, 1], [1166, 0], [1365, 0], [3, 1], [2, 583], [1166, 583], [1365, 1]])
out = []
vs = set(X[:,-1])
for v in vs:
    idxs = X[:,-1] == v
    out.append(np.sort(X[idxs],axis=0))
out = np.array(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy reshape for reshaping this array

```py
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[0, 0], [583, 0], [1166, 0], [1365, 0], [0, 583], [583, 583], [1166, 583], [1365, 583]])
array.reshape(2, 4,2)
```

output:

```
array([[[   0,    0],
        [ 583,    0],
        [1166,    0],
        [1365,    0]],

       [[   0,  583],
        [ 583,  583],
        [1166,  583],
        [1365,  583]]])
```

For detail visit [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.shape.html)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I do. I want to be able to do It on an array with a variable size

Comment: Yes you could it any kind of variable size

Comment: variable size, meaning that I don't know the size of the given array and the number of its unique numbers in one of its columns

Comment: You don't need to know what is the size of the given array but you want to convert that array in a fixed size? is it okay ?